# Why define $(\nabla^2F)(X,Y)=\nabla_X(\nabla_YF)-(\nabla_{\nabla_XY}F)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Why define 
$$(\nabla^2F)(X,Y)=\nabla_X(\nabla_YF)-(\nabla_{\nabla_XY}F)?$$

I can't find the motivation of this definition .I don't know the purpose of defining so.

The more details the better, I am just a beginner in geometry.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't tag this Riemannian geometry question as analytic geometry. If you really want, create a new tag "Geometric Analysis" may be.

Comment: Many authors use this formula as a definition but (as John's answer shows) if you interpret $\nabla^2 = \nabla \nabla$ it follows from the axioms of tensor derivations. Also note that $X,Y \mapsto \nabla_X (\nabla_Y F)$ is not $C^\infty$-linear, so is not a tensor.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Yes, I think for keeping $C^\infty-linear $ is main purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general for a $(p,q)$-tensor $A$, one defines $\nabla A$ as a $(p,q+1)$ tensor by 
$$\nabla A(X, \cdots) = \nabla_XA(\cdots),$$
where $\nabla_X A$ is defined as (for example if $A$ is a $(2,0)$ tensor)
$$\nabla_X A(Y, Z) = \nabla_X(A(Y, Z)) - A(\nabla_X Y, Z) - A(Y, \nabla _X Z).$$

So in our case
$$\begin{split}
\nabla^2 F(X, Y) &= (\nabla \nabla F) (X, Y) \\
&= (\nabla_X \nabla F)(Y) \\
&=  \nabla_X(\nabla F(Y)) - \nabla F(\nabla_XY) \\
&= \nabla_X \nabla_Y F - \nabla_{\nabla_XY} F.
\end{split}$$

Remark: Indeed $\nabla^2 F$ is symmetric:
$$\begin{split} 
\nabla^2 F(X, Y) - \nabla^2 F(Y, X) &= X(YF) - \nabla_{\nabla_X Y} F - Y(XF) + \nabla_{\nabla_YX} F \\
&= X(YF) - Y(XF) - \nabla_{\nabla_XY - \nabla _YX} F \\
&= [X, Y]F - \nabla_{[X, Y]} F \\
&= 0 .
\end{split}$$

Comment: $\nabla A$ should be $(p+1,q)$?

Comment: I think I will use the convention that a $(p,q)$ tensor has $p$-upper indices and $q$ lower indices (It seems it's common, I am not sure). So $\nabla A$ involves adding a new "column" $X = X^i$, so it's adding one more lower indices. (But I do agree that $\nabla A (X, \cdots)$ might should be changed to $\nabla A(\cdots, X)$ then... ) @lanse2pty

Comment: In our case there is no ambiguity as $\nabla^2 F(X, Y) = \nabla^2 F(Y, X)$ (try to show this).

Comment: $\nabla^2F(X,Y)=X^i\partial_iY^j\nabla_jF+X^iY^j\nabla_i\nabla_jF-X^i\nabla_iY^j\nabla_jF-X^iY^j\Gamma_{ij}^k\nabla_k F$, then, exchange X and Y, but it does not  seem the same.

Comment: @lanse2pty : Try to use $XY - YX = [X, Y] = \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X$.

Comment: Whether $\nabla_X\nabla_YF=\nabla_{XY}F$ ?Let me try it .

Comment: Yes, it's true. @lanse2pty

Comment: Can you see the picture below, there seem be some question about $\nabla_X\nabla_YF=\nabla_{XY}F$

Comment: I'm glad you know this. That's why somehow I don't like this notation. @lanse2pty .Writing just $XY F$ might be better.

Comment: This is not true. The left hand side has only first derivative of $F$, while there are second derivative of $F$ on the right hand side. @lanse2pty

Comment: I am totally fuzzy,,,, Let me do it again.

Comment: I get $\nabla^2F(X,Y)-\nabla^2F(Y,X)=R(X,Y)F$.  But $R(X,Y)F$ is not always zero. Are you sure  $\nabla^2F(X,Y)=\nabla^2F(Y,X)$?

Comment: Please see the edit. @lanse2pty

Comment: $YF=\nabla_YF$?

Comment: Yes, indeed we have four notations representing the same thing: $XF = \nabla_X F = dF(X) = \langle X, \nabla F\rangle$.

Comment: I still can't understand $\nabla_X(\nabla_YF)-\nabla_Y(\nabla_XF)=\nabla_{[X,Y]}F$ .

Comment: Your equation is the same as $X(YF) - Y(XF) = [X,Y] F$. @lanse2pty

Comment: @JohnMa  I know they are same. I don't know how to get the equality. I'm lanse2pty,because it's not enough only 50 question 1-month.

Comment: :-)  ,Keep this secret. You misunderstand me, I don't know why $X(YF) - Y(XF) $  equal to $[X,Y] F$ ..

Comment: It's the definition of the Lie bracket $[X, Y] = XY  - YX$. @lanse7pty

Comment: In fact, it is why $\nabla_X(\nabla_YF)-\nabla_Y(\nabla_XF)$ equal to $\nabla_{[X,Y]}F$, and $F$ is a tensor, not a function.It's my mistake.

Comment: ?? I suppose in this question $F$ is a function. @lanse7pty

Comment: Don't talk about this ,I'm too tired.